# Easy factor/enum type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I do data analysis on large single-column datasets, which contain a lot of "enums". For example, a column might contain Not at all, Rarely, Neutral, Sometimes, Always, or NA/empty. Another column might contain Male/Female. I might have half a million rows, and 50 columns across. I am looking into different options for storing and working with this data, and was interested in using Postgres. I see that there is an enum type, however that has to be defined up-front, and is difficult/costly to extend. I am used to working with the factors in R, which just work, internally using ints and lookup tables.

I just did a quick experiment in Postgres with 19000 rows and 40 columns, all tiny factors, but imported as varchars. The table took 10MB space. Compared to a generated table with only ints, which took 2MB space.

Is there an extension to Postgres or some way of getting this functionality automatically? I could of course create a ton of foreign columns, but that seems to be a lot of procedure. I could statically define enums, or I could even keep the lookup-tables in the R/Python script - but all of these seem error-prone, high-overhead, or have poor portability...

Comment: I am not aware of that possibility. Did you consider column-oriented databases since you data analysis on a single column. PostgreSQL is row-oriented DBMS suitable for OLTP, not OLAP.

Comment: Yes, that is definitively something to look at. I have used HDF5 in the past with pytables (it does not provide this feature either, I "emulated" it in software). I also looked at the cstore fdw for Postgres.

Comment: Postgresql 9.1 and above has `ALTER TYPE enumtype ADD VALUE...` which allows to extend after the creation. The size for enums is 4 bytes, the same as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no automatic solution for this.

In most applications, disk space isn't critical.

When disk space *is* critical, data compression by using integers as foreign keys is simple, easily extensible, reliable, and portable. (Enums are among the *least* portable features in SQL database management systems.)

If you have 500k rows of 50 columns, and each column is an integer surrogate key, you're only talking about 100 MB plus the size of referenced tables and indexes. Five times that is 500 MB. In database terms, this is a small database. Heck, sometimes I load 50 *million* rows for testing before I answer a question here.

If I were in your shoes, I'd just read the data (column and referenced table) when I needed it, and use R to transform the data into factors.